# How I set webpack ChunkName in vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have some problem with webpack Chunk !! I have aleady install "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import" below is my setting and import() code. There are only generate entry index.js file into output folder so what do I missing? why don't generate the chunk file 'about.bundle.js'?

**I have ues vue 2 and webpack 4**

#### In my vue router index.js

```
component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */'../views/HelloVue/components/About/about')
```

#### In my Webpack.config.js

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve("../web"),
    filename: "./js/[name].js",
    chunkFilename: './js/[name].bundle.js',
  }
```

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1167

Comment: This dosn't work , By the way for some reason I don't use vue-cli in this project , I need use webpack and set it up manually

Answer (score 0):

If you have typescript, make sure `"removeComments"` option in `tsconfig.json` is set to `false`